# passing a php array through jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I want to pass an array through ajax, but not sure how I would do this.

```
<input type="button" data-array="'.$array.'" id="button" value="click">
```

I know I cant put arrays in html, but I couldnt think of how else to explain what I am trying to accomplish.

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    array = $(this).attr('data-array');
    $.ajax({        
        type    : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        url     : 'ajax.php',
        data    : 'array='+array,
        success : function(data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

So I then want to pass that array variable, $array, through to ajax.php. Is this even possible, if so how is it done? I am guess something to do with json?

Comment: You can either serialize the array or put its elements in separate input elements. For your example a serilization looks just fine, maybe even in JSON itself. Then you can decode it again on the php side by means of a simple `jseon_decode()` call.

Comment: If you do `data-array="'. json_encode($array) .'" ...` you'll get JSON, which is generally easier to work with.

Comment: Oh, I could also implode the array, and explode it in ajax.php, that might be simplest.

Comment: The simplest would be to use JSON, that's why we're suggesting it. jQuery will even parse it as an array for you automagically if it's valid JSON -> http://jsfiddle.net/f89oa5kh/

Comment: Ok, so how do I pass it through the ajax, and how is it received in the ajax.php file?

Comment: Just do `data : {array : $(this).data('array')},` and jQuery will again stringify it automagically, and you'll get it on the serverside with `$_POST['array']`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the array in html you could store it in a session variable and call it later when needed.

```
$_SESSION['dataArray'] = $array;
```